# Не работает выравнивание margin auto в inline-block элементе

Tags: css

В приведенном коде кнопка должна поставиться по центру, но остается все равно слева

```
.promo .promo_btn{
width:259px;
margin:118px auto 0 auto;
height: 63px;
border: solid 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7, #4ce2ff);
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если поменять display на block, всё начинает работать.

```
.promo .promo_btn{
display: block;
width:259px;
margin:118px auto 0 auto;
height: 63px;
border: solid 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1eacc7, #4ce2ff);
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему такое противоречие? Если строчно-блочный элемент, то должны margin работать, а тут не хочет , display : block ему подавай. Двойные стандарты какие то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [спецификации](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) для CSS2 написано так:

> **10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow**
>
> A computed value of 'auto' for 'margin-left' or 'margin-right' becomes a
> used value of '0'.

То есть для `inline-block` значение `margin: auto` будет просто считаться нулём.

Стандарты не двойные, а просто разные для каждого случая. Такое повсеместно. У `margin` их много разных, например можно сказать что для вертикального центрирования подавай `display: flex` или `display: grid` у родителя.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всегда хотел научиться спецификацию читать, никогда не получалось, с английским вроде средне, но не удается

Comment: @РусланКамов это не просто, там очень много чего написано не понятно или не полно, и тащится много прошлых уже принятых раньше вещей. здесь я просто нашел кусок этот, но не факт что можно так хорошо найти для других. Например недавно тут обсуждал один участник стили window через js, и там чтобы понять всё, одной спецификации мало, и она не даёт ответы.

Comment: ,а чтобы Вы посоветовали мне на первых порах? Вот так чтобы искать информацию? Вы очень бегло по спецификации , причем на английском нашли нужное место, я поражен. Не буду же все время тут спрашивать, достану так всех.

Comment: @РусланКамов не знаю что советовать. У меня просто уже глаз набит или чувствую как могли думать программеры в какой-то ситуации, поэтому быстрее нахожу в какую сторону копать. На первых порах так не получится, нужно просто в своих темах вариться долго.

Comment: @РусланКамов Этот ресурс для того и работает, чтобы спрашивать. Вы тут не можете никого достать, если вопрос хорошо оформлен и уважаете других участников, и не задаёте одно и тоже или неадекватно совсем. Правила просто тут всякие подробнее прочтите и всё ок будет.

Comment: этим этот ресурс и прекрасен , множество раз видел на других ресурсах,вместо адекватных ответов когда участник задает -  троллинг, стёб, желание сказать "тебе не место в программировании", однажды я сам на винград  зашел, и как свора псов набросились на меня вместо ответа на вопрос